# Displaying a list of jobs using a Consumer

Tags: java, lambda, consumer

I am studying lambda. But I have a problem to display the results.

```
public class JavaTest {
    
    public static Consumer<Person> consumer1() {
        return person -> {
            String before_job = person.getJob();
            String after_job1 = before_job.replace("PHP programmer", ".NET programmer");
            String after_job2 = before_job.replace("Java programmer", "Python programmer");
            person.setJob(after_job1);
            person.setJob(after_job2);
            System.out.println(after_job1);
            System.out.println(after_job2);
        };
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> results = new ArrayList<Person>();
        
        results.add(new Person("Elsdon", "Jaycob","Java programmer","male",43,2000));
        results.add(new Person("Tamsen", "Brittany","Java programmer","female",23,1500));
        results.add(new Person("Floyd", "Donny","Java programmer","male",33,1800));
        
        System.out.println("=======================================6");
        results.stream().forEach(consumer1());
        
    }
}
```

But when I tried to debug my code, `Consumer` didn't change the jobs in `Person`.
I have a question about how to use `Consumer` perfectly.
Any reply will be thankful. Best regards.

[UPDATE]
When I debugged my codes, I didn't disabled the function codes. It caused the wrong answer. Now I solves my problem.

Comment: Can you add console output for your test? Looking at it, it should change the person. But are you aware that person.setJob(after_job2); overwrites previous person.setJob(after_job1); ? Also what is implementation of Person.setJob?

Comment: I am sorry. When I debugged my codes, I didn't inoperate Function. It caused the wrong answer.

Comment: You are changing before_job twice and operating on the same object. So all Java programmer will change to Python programmer. after_job1 object remains same as no PHP programmer is present in the input and after_job2 changes only. Test it again and check. You can If condition as well the check before updating.  Please paste your output  to make it more clear.